# Gstreamer Gsocket UDP

Tags: c++, udp, gstreamer

I'm trying to connect to a RTP over UDP live video stream. I am trying to use the Gsocket to then apply to the udpsrc. I am unable to connect the the server with the Gsocket. Is there any suggestions anybody has to connect to the video stream?

Comment: If you're using GStreamer you shouldn't need to deal with the GSocket objects directly.  Try using udpsrc like this: gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=5100 ! application/x-rtp,media=video,payload=96,encoding-name=H264 ! rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! autovideosink

Comment: gotcha! so why would gstreamer udpsrc have gsocket?

Comment: GStreamer elements are wrappers for most of the low level work.  If you want to deal with the sockets directly you should discard GStreamer and use something like libav.